# Can I tell spring to use compatibility=NONE when auto-registering schemas for a kafka topic

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-schema-registry

We are using kafka topics for our micro-services to communicate with each other. We are also using schemas to define the content of our topics.

On our various stages we explicitely deploy the schemas for each topic as part of the deployment process. However, on our local developer laptops (where we have a docker container running a local kafka and schema-registry instance) we do not want to do this.

We are using Spring-Boot and `spring-kafka`.

Accordingly, we have the following two config files:

**application.yml**

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.auto.register.schemas=false
```

***application-local.yml**

```
spring.kafka.producer.properties.auto.register.schemas=true
```

This works well, our schemas are automatically registered with the local schema-registry when we write to a kafka-topic for the first time.

However, after we've made some schema changes, our publish now fails telling us that the new schema is not compatible with the previously installed schema. Checking the local schema registry, we see that the auto-registered schema was registered with `compatibility=BACKWARD` whereas on our staged registries we work with `compatibility=NONE` (we're well aware of the issues this may bring with regard to breaking changes -> this is handled in the way we work with our data).

Is there any way to make the auto-registration use `NONE` instead of `BACKWARD`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any new subject will inherit the global compatibility level of the Registry; you cannot set it when registering a schema without making a secondary out-of-band compatibility HTTP request (in other words, prior to actually producing any data which may register the schema on its own).

During local development, I would suggest deleting the schema from your registry until you are content with the schema rather than worrying about local compatibility changes.

You could also set the default compatibility of the container to NONE

Comment: Thanks, setting the default compatibility of the local registry to NONE has solved out issue!